# Visual Studio Database Unit Testing and External Scripts

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I am having a hard time understanding how to make Visual Studio 2010 database unit tests run a .sql file from the filesystem before running tests. If it was pure C# there are a couple of ways to do this, but the DB unit tests seem to be more limited.

Can anyone clue me in?

Thanks.